# Eclipse - Method Suggestion Issues

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if anyone could help me with an issue with Eclipse.

Since I changed the packages in Eclipse, something has changed with the auto completion tool. I can no longer see any public methods when writing the `.`, however, if I manually type the line in there is no compile error.

Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Do you use `eclipse refactor`?

Comment: No I do not think I have used that before, but one of my group might have. What could the issue be with this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've had this issue before, and for me, the content assist settings were broken. The following fixed it:

- Open Eclipse Preferences
- Go to **Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced**
- Make sure that **Other Java Proposals** is selected in the list of proposal kinds.

Comment: For me, what worked was Close Project, then Open Project, and finally Clean Project.

Comment: In my case 'other java proposals' was not in the list, but adding some others fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, it was just called "Java Proposals" but worked just as well.

Answer (score 13):

Go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced Select Java Proposal. Please see the screenshot for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565350/eclipse-method-suggestion-issues#comment12126135_9565457) from [Sorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588773/sorin) is the only answer that worked for me:

> ... what worked was Close Project, then Open Project, and finally
>   Clean Project.